# Jenkins plugin site to ignore certificates

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way that I can tell Jenkins to ignore certificates for the update site.

**Background**

I have an air-gapped Jenkins installation and there is currently [proper way to make a proxy repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548140/jenkins-plugin-repo-as-proxy-repo-when-behind-a-firewall/56321607#56321607). Thus I have the following setup:
- I have modified the `hosts` file on the Jenkins host so that `updates.jenkins-ci.org` points to the host of the internal artifact repo
- There is a reverse-proxy in front of artifact repo which handles traffic for `updates.jenkins-ci.org`

However we are only allowed to use https thus there will be a `name mismatch error` as the certificate does not match the hostname of the artifact repo host

Remark: I don't want to generally disable the checks but only for the update site so the `The Skip Certificate Check plugin` is not the solution for me

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Can you consider using certs signed by your own created CA, either on the artifact repo host or on a specific reverse proxy you control ?

Comment: Well I obviously can use self-signed certificates, but the problem is the host-name missmatch as the hostname of my repo server or reverse proxy is not `updates.jenkins-ci.org`

Comment: I would take a look at the following project and plugin:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/juseppe
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/UpdateSites+Manager+plugin

Comment: Thanks @casey vega didn't knew about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your comment confirming you can use your own signed certificates internally.

One solution would be to replace the current certificate on your repo with a new one holding `updates.jenkins-ci.org` as an alias. [This response on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl/27931596#27931596) has the necessary info to get you going.

Meanwhile, the [plugin higlighted above by @casey vega in the comments](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/UpdateSites+Manager+plugin) (which I didn't know) seems to be a solution much easier to manage.